# iOS datepicker maximum/minimum date doesn't work when you change locale?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

i have a project that i need to switch locale in the app starting setup, however after several testing i realized that the date picker.maximum/minimum is not working when i change to another language other than english. I am using radianttap's language switcher framework to switch the locale at the setup/login screen.

Code to switch language:

```
func checkLanguageSelected(langSelected: String){
    switch langSelected {
    case "English":
        Locale.updateLanguage(code: "en")
    case "မြန်မာ":
        Locale.updateLanguage(code: "my")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This is my code for setting up datepicker:

```
let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
//datePickerView.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "en") as Locale
let maxDateString = "01-Jan-2006"
let minDateString = "01-Jan-1916"
let dateFormatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "en") as Locale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let maxDate:Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: maxDateString)
let minDate:Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: minDateString)
datePickerView.maximumDate = maxDate
datePickerView.minimumDate = minDate
dateOfBirth.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerFromValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

I am using UITextfield linked to IBAction on editing did began to show the datepicker on the textfield "dateOfBirth". Anybody have any idea? As long as the app start in english, then the max/min date will work, but it won't work on another language. I tried setting both datepicker and dateformatter's locale to "en" but it also broke datepicker's max/min date on english setting as well.
Anybody encountered this type of problem before?

Comment: Have you tried setting locale "en" only on date formatter? Initial value is from Gregorian calendar. "my" should use another calendar and Date objects can be used to pass value between calendar. How does it break btw., are values just ignored?

Comment: wow okay, i tried your suggestion and it works, then i wanted to mess around abit and change the locale of the datepicker because the "my" datepicker calenders are not official months name, so i uncommented out the line to change datepicker locale and somehow it works also. Apparently restarting xcode will fix the bug (but cleaning the project wont'). Very weird. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its an xcode bug? Not sure, i restarted the xcode and the changing of locale won't mess with the max/min setting of datepicker anymore.